# Upload app bits in CloudFoundry with python

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

To deploy an app in `CloudFoundry` I am following below steps
1. authenticate to the PaaS
2. create the application
3. create a route for the application
4. associate the route with the application
5. upload the application bits
6. start the app

I am using `cloudfoundry_client` module and first step is cleared and next

```
cl=cloudfoundry_client.CloudFoundryClient("https://api.run.pivotal.io")

cl.init_with_credentials("my uname","mypwd")

data={'name':"test_app1","space_guid":'e989f5b4-b4ad-4129-84d7-44909b992e93',"diego":True}

cl.application._create(data)
#successfully created app I have checked in cf cli

#successfully Associated the route with app also
```

Now I have to upload my app files which are in a zip file. I don't know how to do it. from the `CloudFoundry API` I ended up with https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/226/apps/uploads_the_bits_for_an_app.html , I don't know how to upload my files.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the source code of the [cloudfoundry_client](https://github.com/antechrestos/cf-python-client), it doesn't look like it is possible. According to the API doc, you have to send a PUT request with a multipart body (json + zip file). However the client you are using takes the json data that you give to [`application._update()`](https://github.com/antechrestos/cf-python-client/blob/v0.0.3/src/cloudfoundry_client/entities.py#L15) and [forwards](https://github.com/antechrestos/cf-python-client/blob/v0.0.3/src/cloudfoundry_client/calls.py#L54) it directly to [`requests.put()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). The `files` argument of the `put` method is never used, so there is no chance you can upload a file with this module.

I suggest double-checking with the developer of the module and do one of the following:

- Ask him if he can add the functionality
- Add the functionality yourself
- Find another CF client (I only know the CLI, but haven't searched)

Comment: Actualy `put` method is also there i am using `put` method for some of my requirements. The problem is I don't know how to give the file, that is open zip file in `rb` mode and give it as a parameter or directly `zip` file name.

Comment: Yes that's what I am explaining: the put method is there, but it does not offer a way to send multipart data, it lets you sends json only.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to upload my bits using python, using curl I am able to send the bits through that url. I want that in python.